# How do I fix the Tagged Annotations fail/error for accessibility for links using pdfbox java?

Tags: java, pdf, accessibility, pdfbox, tagged-pdf

Found the solution by using adobe - https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-I-fix-Tagged-Annotations-fail-error-accessibility-links-q228128.aspx

How can I add Link-OBJR (object reference to link annotation) using pdfbox.

```
       `PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
        PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
        position.setLowerLeftX(PDFUtils.lw_lft_x);
        position.setLowerLeftY(PDFUtils.lw_lft_y);
        position.setUpperRightX(PDFUtils.tp_rgt_x);
        position.setUpperRightY(PDFUtils.tp_rgt_y);
        txtLink.setRectangle(position);
        txtLink.setHidden(true); 
        txtLink.getCOSObject().setInt(COSName.STRUCT_PARENT,1); 
        PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI();
        action.setURI(PDFUtils.link);
        txtLink.setAction(action);
        page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
        PDObjectReference pd= new PDObjectReference();
        pd.setReferencedObject(txtLink);
        structureElement.appendKid(pd);
        currentSection.appendKid(structureElement);
        structureElement formBuilder.addContentToParent(COSName.P, null, page, structureElement, PDFUtils.mcid);`
```

Tagged using above code-

[image: Tagged using above code]

Tagged document reference- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n_T361G6LTNLycQbw-3gP2nmBV-oTJdR/view?usp=sharing

Looking for below structure

[image: Looking for like this structure]

Comment: *"Found the solution by using adobe"* - does that mean you already found a solution to your question here? Or are you asking how to implement that solution using pdfbox?

Comment: Oh, this is rather advanced stuff. Please download PDFDebugger and activate "show internal structure", and look at the structure tree of your PDF. Compare this with a "good" PDF and decide what you want to add. It's probably something in /StructTreeRoot/K, something in /StructTreeRoot/ParentTree and something in the annotation itself. The PDFBox type for the OBJR thing is PDObjectReference.  You can also look at the structure tree with "doc.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot()". This is done a lot in PDFMergerUtilityTest.java in the source code download.

Comment: @mkl- I'm asking how to implement that solution using pdfbox.

Comment: @Tilman I have written above code to tag "Link" in pdf but it is failing in accessibility checker. The reason which I found for failing is "Link-OBJR" type tag is missing under the "Link tag". I'm asking how to add "Link-OBJR" type tag under "Link tag" using pdfbox .
Please refer the screenshot.

Comment: I don't have a "good" file, so I don't know what is missing, compared to your file. Adobe Professional shows a user-friendly view of things, but the PDF format is much more complex. As I wrote, you'll probably have to make 3 different changes.

Comment: "The PDFBox type for the OBJR thing is PDObjectReference". This works for me.   

Thank you @Tilman.

Comment: @Tilman After adding the Link-OBJR under Link tag , I'm still getting the same error "Tagged Annotations fail/error".
am I missing any other parameters ?

Comment: That's what I meant "3 different changes". I have only a partial understanding of this, but I know that /K, /ParentTree and the reference in the annotation somehow belong together. That's why I'd need to see a "good" PDF to decide what is missing.

Comment: Hi, @Tilman I have uploaded both Good and Bad pdf. Please let me know what I am missing in bad pdf and how I can achieve that.

Good-Tagged by Adobe
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iz8xnrd-vPfkexi2w8lgBieLMcHWU6Yg/view?usp=sharing)


And  Bad- Tagged by me
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OL-qciOw0cgUTAi9TvD8Pymsfz6iARqE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, after having a look, this requires a lot of learning, even from me who has done some work on merging structuretrees last christmas. The only thing I understand is that the Root/StructTreeRoot/ParentTree/ gets a new element with the value of ParentTreeNextKey + 1 (and ParentTreeNextKey is then updated). But I haven't understood where to insert in the /StructTreeRoot/K tree :-(