# PDF Link Annotation unable to tag properly?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to tag link annotation using PDFBOX, Its tagging fine([refrence code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59172513/how-do-i-fix-the-tagged-annotations-fail-error-for-accessibility-for-links-using)). But after tagging if I open tag properties in adobe its empty. 
[image]

Next after this annotation tagging the images also throwing some error (even though alt-text is there) like
[image]

Here the [error file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RQlam80liClhvpHI5WVvjInE0X88S-6l/view?usp=sharing) which is the first image right side one, Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: One of the two annotations does not have a StructParent entry. I also don't see it in the structure tree. There may be more problems, I don't know much in that field.

Comment: Yes, I know I am talking about existing annotation in StructParent tree. That one only cause error.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I updated the question please check. there is a difference in adobe tagged vs tagged by me. please tell how can i add that lke 1:4.

Comment: I see my first comment was unclear, I meant "ParentTree". I didn't see your annotation there. And the StructParent entry, this is a number, and this was missing in your annotation.